# Trying to find critical point of a function with definition

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be non-constant and holomorphic in a neighborhood of p. The order of $p$ as a zero of the function $f-f(p)$ is called the local degree of $f$ and denoted $\deg(f,p)$:
> $$\deg(f,p)=ord(f-f(p),p)$$.
> When $\deg(f,p)>1$, equivalently when $f^\prime(p)=0$ we call $p$ a critical point.

Now if we look at an example: $P(z)=3z^4-4z^3+4$ by looking at the derivative $P^\prime=12z^2(z-1)$ we can tell $0,1$ are critical points of $P$.

But if we try to look at $P(z)$ and find the critical point without looking at the derivative. According to the definition, we want to find ponits $p$ such that $3z^4-4z^3+4-(3p^4-4p^3+4) $ has order strictly greater than 1. (i.e. find $p$ such that the leading and the first coefficients become 0). In this particular example, we simply solve for $-3p^4+4p^3=0$, which I can see 0 is a critical point. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to argue 1 is also a critical point without looking at the derivative.

Comment: You should find the coefficients become zero when the polynomial is in $z-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to check that $1$ is a root of order $\ge2$ of $P(z)-P(1)$ is:
$$P(z)=3+(z-1)^2(3z^2+2z+1).$$
Or if you prefer:
$$P(1+h)=3+h^2(\dots).$$
Or if you do not know in advance which critical point(s) to check:
$$P(p+h)-P(p)=\dots=12p^2(p-1)h+h^2(\dots).$$